# Adjusting 2 monitors to have the same brightness/contrast

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup on Linux, with both monitors being Phillips 109S. One is observably brighter than the other, and I could not make them reach the same level, and it's quite disturbing, e.g. one of them tends to add more 'gray' to the color - pure white is not visible.

Is there anything I can do to make them *except* getting a new monitor?

---

*Technical info*:

- the video card is a GeForce 7100GS;
- the monitors have been tweaked to have the same settings.

Answer (score 2):

I've *attempted* to divine the score on the nVidia site, but to no avail so I'll just ask. Are they both connected via DVI, or is one on DVI and the other VGA? In essence, if they're connected differently then there's usually no way to get them setup correctly (although a monitor calibrator will of course help if you can set the gamma, etc. separately for each deskop).

I presume you've also checked that the gamma and colo(u)r settings, etc. are the same for each monitor within the nVivia display panel advanced settings?

Comment: You're right, one is DVI and one is VGA. I'll try a calibration and see how that turns out.

Answer (score 1):

You can borrow or buy monitor calibrator with support for Linux. Or next way is manualy calibrating through monitor OSD.

You can use color profile, but if both monitors have same configuration and colors are different, it's not working.